# Using User Profile automatically load information into form fields

Tags: python, django

In my pervious [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70931994/save-user-who-submitted-formdjango) I asked how I can automatically save the user submitting the form. I found the `form_valid` method to be the best in that case. However in my models I also have a user profile model like this

models.py

```
....
class Profile(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  title = models.CharField(max_length=24)
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
  email = models.EmailField(max_length=64)
  phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=12)
  department = models.ForeignKey(Department,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
  supervisor = models.ForeignKey('self',blank=True,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
...
```

As you can see I used the One to One method to make my UserProfile

As before in my models.py I have my reports model

```
...
class Report(models.Model):
  id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True,default=uuid.uuid1,editable=False)
  department = models.ForeignKey(Company,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
  user= models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
  submission_date= models.DateField(auto_now=True) #invisible to user
  submission_time = models.TimeField(auto_now=True) #invisible to ,user
  date = models.DateField(default=now,blank=False)
  time = models.TimeField(default=now,blank=False,help_text="hh:mm:ss")
  location = PlainLocationField()
  building = models.ForeignKey(bld,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
  size = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  notes = models.TextField(blank=True)
   def __str__(self):
     return f'{self.date} {self.time} ({self.department})
...
```

My question how I can make it so that the department field will load from the user profile? I would hope to eventually make it possible for users in the same department to be able to view and update each others Reports.

As before:

form.py

```
class ReportForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Report
        fields = '__all__'
        location = PlainLocationField()
    def redirect():
        return redirect("Report")
```

views.py

```
class ReportCreate(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    Template = "templates\reports\Report.html"
    model = Report
    fields = '__all__'
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.instance.save()
        return super(ReportCreate, self).form_valid(form)
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('Report')
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('Report', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you link `Report` to `User`, rather than to `Profile`?
If you already create `Profile` as 1to1 for `User` then, from an application design perspective, it would be the better choice to link to `Profile` rather than to `User`

Comment: ...I'm guessing that makes since now that I think about sorry I've been pulling an all nighter. I guess my concern is the profile data loaded from the user data upon login. Sorry if I'm not wording that right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advise you to use `related_name` in your `ForeignKeys`. Set the `department` field of both models as following:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    ...
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='profiles')
    ...

class Report(models.Model):
    ...
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='reports')
    ...
```

From now on, `Department` objects that are related to `User.Profile` you can access like that:

```
Department.profiles.all()           # it returns QuerySet of all related to Department Profile objects
Department.reports.all()            # it returns QuerySet of all related to Department Report objects
```

And you can use it in making QuerySet for user:

```
Report.objects.filter(department=self.request.user.profile.department)
# it returns all Report objects, that have exactly the same department as the user
```

Or using our new relationship:

```
department = self.request.user.profile.department
reports_for_user = department.reports.all()
```

But I can see one problem. You are using `Company` model for `ForeignKey` in Report. It has to be the same `Department` model for both `Profile` and `Report` models for such easy option to work. Also you definitely should not mix naming in single project. You can set relation with `Company` as another field:

```
company = models.ForeignKey(Company, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here are some steps to help you autofill some fields:

1. Get the user from self.request.user. [How to access current user in Django class based view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33809345/how-to-access-current-user-in-django-class-based-view)
2. Get the profile: [get user profile in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13460426/get-user-profile-in-django)
3. Pass the required fields as context variables: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-pass-additional-context-into-a-class-based-view-django/
4. Pass it into javascript. [How can I pass my context variables to a javascript file in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683922/how-can-i-pass-my-context-variables-to-a-javascript-file-in-django)
5. Set the value like this: [Set the value of an input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609130/set-the-value-of-an-input-field)

DONE!

Comment: If you need any help then please ask. 

Comment: He asked ;) Don't paste answer in links in StackOverflow, please. You can use them to additionaly point somethig, but you have actually more links than text in your answer :)